How to Batch and Timeout Tasks with RabbitMQ in Node.js?
I'm working on a project that interacts with the blockchain using Node.js and RabbitMQ. I need to implement a system where tasks are batched into an array before being sent to the blockchain. The requirements are:

Each worker should collect up to 5 tasks and combine them into an array and send the array to the blockchain.
If a worker has fewer than 5 tasks but the first task has been waiting for at least 5 minutes, the worker should send the available tasks to the blockchain anyway (as an array of course).

I know I can write and handle the timeout or the tasks manually, but I was just wondering if there is a way to handle it purely using RabbitMQ workers.
I asked ChatGPT and here's the answer, and the code handles everything itself, since I'm new to RabbitMQ, I wanted to know if there's a better way to handle it.
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
const { sendToBlockchain } = require('./blockchain'); // Function to send tasks to the blockchain

const QUEUE = 'task_queue';
const MAX_TASKS = 5;
const MAX_WAIT_TIME = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5 minutes in milliseconds

let taskBuffer = [];
let timer = null;
let firstTaskTime = null;

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(error0, connection) {
  if (error0) {
    throw error0;
  }
  connection.createChannel(function(error1, channel) {
    if (error1) {
      throw error1;
    }
    channel.assertQueue(QUEUE, {
      durable: true
    });

    console.log("Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", QUEUE);

    channel.consume(QUEUE, function(msg) {
      const task = msg.content.toString();
      console.log("Received %s", task);

      if (taskBuffer.length === 0) {
        firstTaskTime = Date.now();
        startTimer();
      }

      taskBuffer.push(task);

      if (taskBuffer.length >= MAX_TASKS) {
        processTasks();
      }
    }, {
      noAck: true
    });
  });
});

function startTimer() {
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    if (taskBuffer.length > 0) {
      processTasks();
    }
  }, MAX_WAIT_TIME);
}

function processTasks() {
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
  }

  if (taskBuffer.length > 0) {
    sendToBlockchain(taskBuffer)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Tasks sent to blockchain:', taskBuffer);
        taskBuffer = [];
        firstTaskTime = null;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error sending tasks to blockchain:', error);
      });
  }
}

